# Image opening in FIrefox, but not chome using ng-src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, google-chrome

I am using ng-src to load a remote image to my web app. In Firefox it loads the images perfectly fine. In Chrome, however, it cannot find the image. Here is the HTML element I am using:

```
<a href="#/wep/{{wep.name}} | {{skin.skinName}}"><img ng-src="http://csgostash.com/img/skins/s{{skin.imgNumber}}.png" style="width:50px;height:50px" /></a>
```

[Here](http://csgostash.com/img/skins/s255.png) is an example URL that you can open in your browser to display the image.

I notice when you open the URL it takes the 'http://' out from before the URL. And changes it to simply 'csgostash.com/img/skins/s255.png'. This could be part of why it is not loading I am guessing, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I am finding that the image is loading fine in Chrome!

Comment: @GaneshKumar I actually just tried hard coding in "http://csgostash.com/img/skins/s255.png" and it worked for me too. that means {{skin.imgNumber}} is causing me problems.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that only certain urls work with simply the "s{{number}}" syntax. csgostash.com uses the wear also on some of their urls. For instance: "s{{number}}fn" will pull up the correct image.